# How should I map an entity to two tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Please forgive the awkward title. I'm not entirely sure how to phrase it

I have an entity, let's call it `A`. `A` is pulled from a spreadsheet weekly and then stored in a table. The spreadsheet is cumulative, as in data pulled from 6 weeks ago is included in the spreadsheet from 1 week ago.

Now, sometimes this data will be the same and won't need changing. Sometimes it will need changing. I want to keep the primary table full of the most up to date data. That is, as entities are updated, the outdated entity is deleted and the newer entity is inserted in its place.

When an `A` entity has changed, I create a `Conflict`, such that this `Conflict` has a Guid, a DateTime of the conflict discovery, a comment, and a copy of the old entity (so that we can see what has changed and so forth), plus related conflicts. The related conflicts works fine, however I'd like to know how I can persist the old entities.

I could do a component mapping, but that just explodes the table and I believe that I could do this in a more "pretty" fashion.

My `Conflict` is mapped as follows :

```
public class ConflictAMapping : ClassMap<Conflict<A>>
{
    public ConflictAMapping()
    {
        Id(c => c.Guid);
        Map(c => c.DateOfConflict);
        Map(c => c.Comment);
        HasMany(c => c.RelatedConflicts)
            .KeyColumn("ConflictKey")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("RelatedConflicts");
        References<A>(c => c.OriginalEntity)
            .Column("FK_IssueNumber")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

And my `A` mapping

```
public class GSFEntityMapping : ClassMap<GSFEntity>
{
    public GSFEntityMapping()
    {

     ... unrelated properties blah blah ...
        HasMany(g => g.Conflicts).KeyColumn("theKey")
            .Table("Conflicts")
            .AsBag().Cascade.All()
    }
}
```

The `Conflict` table looks like this:

```
Guid|DateOfConflict|CommentFK_IssueNumber|ConflictKey|theKey
```

The `A` table doesn't have anything related to conflicts in it (just the actual properties).

So how can I map the old entities? Do I have to generate a new class for old `A` entities or is there some way I can do this in Fluent/NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have classes like this

```
class Issue
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Key { get; set; }   // same for all versions of the issue
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

class Conflict<T>
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual T OriginalEntity { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateOfConflict { get; set; }
    public virtual string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual string IssueKey { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Conflict<T>> RelatedConflicts { get; protected set; }
}
```

then mappings with

- removed Inverse because there is no backreference in Conflict like RelatesTo
- Cascade.None() on Conflicts because deleting IssueVersion should not automaticly delete all Conflicts of the Issue
- renamed some columns for clarity
- a second mapping for archived Issues

```
public class ConflictAMapping : ClassMap<Conflict<Issue>>
{
    public ConflictAMapping()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(c => c.DateOfConflict);
        Map(c => c.Comment);
        HasMany(c => c.RelatedConflicts)
            .KeyColumn("RelatedToConflict")
            .Cascade.All();
        References(c => c.OriginalEntity)
            .EntityName("ArchivedIssue")
            .Column("FK_Issue_id")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class IssueMapping : ClassMap<Issue>
{
    public IssueMapping()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(c => c.Key);
        Map(c => c.Created);
        HasMany(g => g.Conflicts)
            .KeyColumn("IssueKey")
            .PropertyRef("Key")
            .Cascade.None();
    }
}

public class ArchivedIssueMapping : IssueMapping
{
    public ArchivedIssueMapping()
    {
        Table("ArchivedIssues");
        EntityName("ArchivedIssue");
    }
}
```

ArchivedIssues would create a table which are a exact copy of the Issue table. and using it should be easy

```
var oldIssueVersion = session.Get<Issue>(newIssueVersion.Id);
session.Delete(oldIssueVersion);

var conflict = new Conflict<Issue>() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), IssueKey = oldIssueVersion.Key, OriginalEntity = oldIssueVersion, DateOfConflict = DateTime.Now };
session.Save(conflict);
session.Save(newIssueVersion);
```

querying old Issues would be

```
var oldIssueVersions = session.CreateCriteria<Issue>("ArchivedIssues")
    .List<Issue>();
```